# Networked programs in Python

Tags: python

```
import socket
mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysock.connect(('www.py4inf.com', 80))
mysock.send('GET http://www.py4inf.com/code/romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\n\n')
while True:
    data = mysock.recv(512)
    if ( len(data) < 1 ) :``
       break
    print data
mysock.close()
```

I am a bit confused, can anyone in short explain the above code?

Comment: Please check this link - https://pymotw.com/2/socket/tcp.html

Comment: What in particular don't you understand?